# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x104a67320) to 'NSDictionary' (0x104a68108)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to parsing JSON from response. But I got this error 
 My code is.

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil {
        print("error = \(error)")
        return
    }
    do {
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

         let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

         let str = json["ResultMsg"] as! NSString     
         print ("ResultMsg = " + (str as String))

    }catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error : " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}).resume()
```

and console log is:

> responseString = Optional("{\"ResuleCode\":\"1\",\"ResultMsg\":\"SUCCESS\",\"Result\":[{\"UserIdx\":\"4138\",\"Email\":\"testapi@test.co.kr\",\"UserName\":\"test1\",\"Pwd\":\"v+Mb90ZS+Y5Qt9DfuBcJtQ==\",\"Phone\":\"012345678913\",\"AppKey\":\"\",\"LoginDt\":\"9/23/2016 1:12:18 PM\",\"LogoutDt\":\"9/1/2016 10:36:02 AM\",\"RegDt\":\"8/31/2016 9:26:04 AM\",\"DelDt\":\"\",\"KeywordTime\":\"60\",\"KeywordEnabled\":\"1\",\"FastEnabled\":\"1\",\"KeywordStartTime\":\"08:30:00\",\"KeywordEndTime\":\"15:30:00\",\"FastStartTime\":\"08:00:00\",\"FastEndTime\":\"15:30:00\",\"IsFirst\":\"NOT_FIRST\",\"IsFastNews\":\"1\",\"IsKeywordNews\":\"1\",\"KeywordStartDt\":\"\",\"KeywordEndDt\":\"\"}]}")
>   **Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10abdf320) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10abe0108).**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: put breakpoint and check which line is throwing this error?

Comment: let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary  --> this line is problem.. signal SOGABRT

Comment: @MoonJikLee Can you show your actual json response instead of showing us xcode response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do{
    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary

    print("parse success")
}catch{
    print("parse error")
}
```

Comment: "if let son = xxxxx"  line has an error. "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSDoctionary'.

Comment: `as? NSDictionary`  or Better `as? [String:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this code works.

```
if let responseData = responseString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
{
  let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: .AllowFragments)                
  print(json)
}
```

But I don't know the reason exactly.. Thanks all anyway

Comment: This is not the right way from coping my answer and giving the answer.

Comment: First you have ask for answer and then you are coping my answer and posting as answer can you please tell me what is difference between your answer and my one?